# Persistent Connections With HTTPS not working

Tags: rest, ssl, jersey, jax-rs, embedded-tomcat-7

I have enabled one Rest service with TLS/SSL.
While making calls to one of the APIs, for each request new connection is getting created (Persistent Connection is not working), SSL handshake is happening which is creating a huge impact on the latency. I checked the request headers (from client) and found the Connection: Keep-Alive and Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=20 are present. I also checked the response(from the server) and didn't find the Connection: Close (also tried to set the Connection and Keep-Alive forcefully), which indicates that server is not closing the connection.But still for every request new connection is getting created.

**Client Side Description**

Jersey Client + Apache Connector

**Server Side Description**

Embedded Tomcat

Though at the client side, doing Response.close() (or readEntity) is recommended. But I think It closes the connection so how to use the persistent connections as well as Response.close()/readEntity() at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The keepalive timeout you have mentioned is 10 milli seconds. Increase it a higher value for example 60,000 for 1 minute.

Hope this Helps!

Regards,
Eby

Comment: did you get the issues solved by increasing the timeout value?